# The icon is duplicated

Tags: node.js, express

I have a nodejs/express application
(Note: I'm noob in these technologies)

and for some reason the folowing jade:

```
                  li#nav-name
                    a(href='/path/to/page.html')
                       i.icon_profile
                       span Page Name
```

Is transformed into :

```
<li id="nav-name">
      <a href="/path/to/page.html">
      <i class="icon_profile">
          <span style="font-family: 'ElegantIcons'"></span>
      </i><span>Page Name</span></a>
</li>
```

instead of :

```
<li id="nav-name">
      <a href="/path/to/page.html">
      <i class="icon_profile"></i>
           <span>Page name</span>
      </a>
</li>
```

So the icon is showed in double.

**Where should I look into this?**

Note: I am setting the flavico.ico in the app.js

```
app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.set('views',path.join(_dirname,'views'))
app.set('view engine','jade')
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

```
li#nav-name
  a(href='/path/to/page.html')
    span.i.icon_profile
    span Page name
```

so I added the icon in a span.

In the requests I had no double favico request so that wasn't my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the hierarchy of your elements in your jade template leading up to this. Your first example:

```
li#nav-name
  a(href='/path/to/page.html')
    i.icon_profile
    span Page name
```

is correct.

What you see being rendered in jade is the following:

```
li#nav-name
  a(href='/path/to/page.html')
    i.icon_profile
      span(style="font-family: 'ElegantIcons'")
    span Page Name
```

So, if you are seeing the latter, but your Jade template reflects the first, you should evaluate how you are setting the flavico.ico (especially if you are doing it with CSS). It seems to be that you are injecting flavico.ico *after* the jade template is compiled.

Comment: I inject the flavico in the app.js. First I do a 

app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico')); 

and only then I do a app.set('views',...) and a app.set('view engine','jade'); How should I do? And the thing is that I have the feeling that only the icons are duplicated (not the web calls)